# Django 2.1 TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_delete'

Tags: django

My code:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user      = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    following = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='followed_by')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.following.all().count())
```

My error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_delete'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, a m2m, has no `on_delete` parameter.

Comment: Thanks, have seen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield), it seems that the field `ManyToManyField` does not have an argument called `on_delete`.

Remove that argument for the field `following`:

```
...
user = models.OneToOneField(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='profile')
following = models.ManyToManyField(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    related_name='followed_by')
...
```

Comment: if i remove it throws an exception TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'

Comment: @ezra you only need to remove `on_delete` from the second field (`following`), not the other one. Are you sure that is whats throwing the error?

Comment: Thanks, am new to django

Comment: @ezra I'm not sure what your last comment implies; did you get it working now? If not, please add the full error stacktrace to your question, so we can keep searching for the cause.