# Using pure HTML forms in Django views

Tags: html, django, forms, django-models, django-views

SO I'm tryng to create a Django site using HTML forms.The form takes in vendor choice and amount, which is then needed to be passed into views. The employee table's balance needs to be updated, with the amount paid deducted from the balance of the current logged in user, and an entry needs to be added to the transaction table stating the details, with credit = 0, rest info taken from form. How can this be done?

Given below are my files:
html:

```
<form method="POST" action="/profiles/updatingBalance">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="1" id="defaultUnchecked" name="defaultRadios">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultUnchecked">Vendor 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="2" id="defaultUnchecked" name="defaultRadios">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultUnchecked">Vendor 2</label>
    </div>  
    <input type="" class="form-control" id="amount1" name="amt" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter amount">
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import django
import datetime
# Create your models here.

class vendor(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=20, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(maxlength=30, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class employee(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.CharField(max_length=20, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class transaction(models.Model):
    vendor_id = models.ForeignKey(vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    emp_id = models.ForeignKey(employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    debit = models.IntegerField()
    credit = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateField(_("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
```

Here's the views.py I tried. I got till updating emplyee table's balance(not sure if it's correct):

```
def updatingBalance(request):
if request.method=="POST":
    ven_id = request.POST["defaultRadios"]
    amount = request.POST["amt"]
    x = employee.objects.filter(id = request.User.id)
    x.balance = x.balance - amount
    p = transaction(vendor_id =ven_id.value, emp_id = request.User.id, debit=amount, credit=0)
    p.save()
    return render(request, 'profiles/userLogin.html', employee)
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('profiles/userLogin.html'))
```

I am confused as to how data can be taken from pure html forms( I'm a beginner), and how that info can be used to get my desired results. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the data from form you should pass the view that will process the information in the action attribute of the form, then with request.POST dictionary you can extract the data that you want.

html:

```
<form method="POST" action="/Yourapp/theview/">
    your html
</form>
```

views:

```
def theview(request):
  amount=request.POST["amt"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs! How do I differentiate in the views.py file, which radio button has been selected? Also, I've updated the views.py functions, kindly let me know if it looks good enough to work!

Comment: You should give a different name to the radio inputs so when you submit the form, in the request.POST dictionary will only appears the radio selected.
Now if you want to return to the same page that you were you must use this:
`
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
`

Comment: Can it be accessed by giving them different values? Setting different names would mean allowing user to select both at once, which I don't want to happen. Also, I updated my views.py, do let me know if it looks good now! Thanks!

Comment: Also, am I using the correct way to save into transaction model?

Comment: then let them with the same name.
Please don't change the return that a gave you before, just literally copy and paste it

Comment: Yes you are,  do you want it to set a 0 in the credit of every transaction?

Comment: Ah, okay. Yes, I want to set credit to 0 in every transaction.

Comment: On making migrations, I am getting an error: _super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_delete'_ . Any idea what's going wrong? It's showing error in `id = models.CharField(max_length=20, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)`

Comment: check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312373/django-2-1-typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-on-delete